# Analysing annual deforestation for multiple polygons in google earth engine

Tags: arrays, for-loop, export, google-earth-engine

I want to **analyse** and **extract** the total annual deforestation between 2001-2021 using the [Hansen forest change](https://glad.earthengine.app/view/global-forest-change#dl=1;old=off;bl=off;) dataset in Google Earth Engine.

For that, I use a feature collection containing (let's say) sub-national boundaries. The code has referred to as `Shape`, which has about 8-9k polygons.

The code that analyses annual deforestation (area in km2) for each shape (subset of Feature Collection `Shapes`) and saves it as an array is pasted below (*this part works fine*):

```java
var annualforestloss = function(ID) 
{
  // Get a feature collection with just the custom shapefile feature.
  // Shape contains multiple features (polygons)
 // Use any shapefile, if mine doesn't work
  var geometry = Shape.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ID', ID));
  //print(geometry);
  Map.addLayer(geometry);
  
  // Get the loss image.
  // This dataset is updated yearly, so check for the latest version.
  var gfc2021 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2021_v1_9');
  var lossImage = gfc2021.select(['loss']);
  
  //Converting m2 to km2
  var lossAreaImage = lossImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1000000);
  
  var lossYear = gfc2021.select(['lossyear']);
  var lossByYear = lossAreaImage.addBands(lossYear).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1
      }),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  //print(lossByYear);
 
  var statsFormatted = ee.List(lossByYear.get('groups'))
    .map(function(el) {
      var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
      return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), d.get('sum')];
    });
  var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());
  //print(statsFormatted)
  //print(statsDictionary)
  
  // Since there has been no forest loss for some years, the code above does not include those years. 
  // To remedy that, we use another dictionary with values as zero and later combine them without overlap
  var dict1 = ee.Dictionary({
  "2001": 0, "2002": 0, "2003": 0,   "2004": 0,   "2005": 0,   "2006": 0,   "2007": 0, "2008": 0,
  "2009": 0,   "2010": 0,   "2011": 0,  "2012": 0,  "2013": 0,  "2014": 0,  "2015": 0,  "2016": 0,
  "2017": 0,  "2018": 0,  "2019": 0,  "2020": 0,  "2021": 0,});
  
  statsDictionary = statsDictionary.combine(dict1, false);
  //print(statsDictionary)
  
  // Platting chart
  /*
  var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({
    array: (statsDictionary.values()),
    axis: 0,
    xLabels: statsDictionary.keys()
  }).setChartType('LineChart')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Yearly Forest Loss (ID-'+ID+')',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '####'},
      vAxis: {title: 'Area (square kilometer)'},
      legend: { position: "none" },
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3
    });
    print(chart)
    */
    
    // Adding 'ID' for seamless data analysis in python
    return statsDictionary.values().add(ID)
};
```

However, the problem I am facing is: **Looping through the features in `Shapes`**: Although I know that 'for loops' are not recommended, I am limited by my ability to use `map()` function in GEE, which returns some client/server error.

```java
// This function combines results from arrays in a loop
var combinearray = function(array1, array2)
{
  var arraynew =   (ee.Array.cat([array1, array2], 0))
  return arraynew
}

// Size of the features (total shapes about 8664)
print(Shape.size())

//**Limited by skill to run it with 'map' function. ##########  Please help!**!!!!!!!############

// Works fine for less loops. Hangs for double digit loops
var list = (annualforestloss(0))
for (var ID = 1; ID <= 6; ID++) {
  var listnew = (annualforestloss(ID))
  var list = (combinearray(list, listnew))
}
print(list)

//reshaping the array for export
var combinedarray = (list.reshape([7,22]))

print('--')
print(combinedarray)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
The following link can be used to see the code editor: https://code.earthengine.google.com/cd335cd1356dc69e3c9adc4ba9710bcb

Comment: Have you tried reduceRegions instead of looping through the shapes? Have you looked at the official best practices guide for this operation? https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#reduceregion-vs.-reduceregions-vs.-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

I think using ReduceRegions() should do the trick. Here is a sample code (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fdvps95%2Fdefault%3AHansen_Annual_ForestLoss)

The reduceRegion() maps the functions across multiple polygons. I hope this answers your question. I would suggest you follow the tutorials from "Spatial thoughts"- Ujwal gandhi does an excellent job in breaking down the concepts.

Good luck!

Comment: You are adding the sample code link to the private user project. Not useful for others as they cannot open that link